# linux interface based routing with two interfaces

Tags: linux, qnetworkaccessmanager

i have 2 interfaces on linux instance. both have static IPs . i have traffic from outside world coming to eth0(208.67.x.x) and inside my server i want the traffic to be redirected to eth1(192.168.X.x) to talk to any application inside.

Please help me on the route configs ..and can I do that on linux instance?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple package called **Firestarter**. Firestarter internally edits *iptables* which are the actual rules to forward packets from source to destinations inside the linux kernel. Please follow the following guidelines to solve your problem. Note that I have given command line examples below but there is also a gui to help you with the setup.

1. Install firestarter on ubuntu using the command in the shell
   *sudo apt-get install firestarter*
2. Define the external and internal interfaces in the */etc/firestarter/configuration* file at appropriate places.
3. Select dhcp server on/off if you wish to run dhcp server on internal network interface.
4. You can also define rules for inbound and outbound traffic as firestarter is also a firewall. The rules can be defined in */etc/firestarter/inbound* and */etc/firestarter/outbound* folders.

For more information on iptables and firestarter visit :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Hope this helps you with your problem. Thanks!